# Google Tasks API from Android - Access Not Configured

Tags: android, google-tasks-api

I believe this is a common problem. Even this documentation points it out: http://samples.google-api-java-client.googlecode.com/hg/tasks-android-sample/instructions.html

I have created a project for my Android app here: https://cloud.google.com/console/start/api?id=tasks and turned on Tasks API. Inside the project for the Android, I set up SHA1 key and name of my package (:com.gruszczy.eisenhower). The same package name is inside `AndroidManifest.xml`. And yet, when I try to run my app, I get an error below. Does anyone know, what I am missing or how I could debug this somehow?

```
11-05 23:21:43.841    6060-6093/com.gruszczy.eisenhower W/System.err﹕ com.google.api.client.googleapis.json.GoogleJsonResponseException: 403 Forbidden
11-05 23:21:43.841    6060-6093/com.gruszczy.eisenhower W/System.err﹕ {
11-05 23:21:43.841    6060-6093/com.gruszczy.eisenhower W/System.err﹕ "code": 403,
11-05 23:21:43.841    6060-6093/com.gruszczy.eisenhower W/System.err﹕ "errors": [
11-05 23:21:43.849    6060-6093/com.gruszczy.eisenhower W/System.err﹕ {
11-05 23:21:43.849    6060-6093/com.gruszczy.eisenhower W/System.err﹕ "domain": "usageLimits",
11-05 23:21:43.849    6060-6093/com.gruszczy.eisenhower W/System.err﹕ "message": "Access Not Configured",
11-05 23:21:43.849    6060-6093/com.gruszczy.eisenhower W/System.err﹕ "reason": "accessNotConfigured"
11-05 23:21:43.849    6060-6093/com.gruszczy.eisenhower W/System.err﹕ }
11-05 23:21:43.849    6060-6093/com.gruszczy.eisenhower W/System.err﹕ ],
11-05 23:21:43.849    6060-6093/com.gruszczy.eisenhower W/System.err﹕ "message": "Access Not Configured"
11-05 23:21:43.849    6060-6093/com.gruszczy.eisenhower W/System.err﹕ }
11-05 23:21:43.857    6060-6093/com.gruszczy.eisenhower W/System.err﹕ at com.googl
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I have deleted the project and recreated it several times. At one point it started working. I guess must have been some temporary fluke.